# what is the advantages if a standard supports SOAP Envelopes

Tags: web-services, soap

because i read that one of the advantages of [WS-Discovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Discovery) that it
"Support both SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2 Envelopes"
so what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some slight differences between the messages generated under the two different SOAP standards - the fact that both are supported increases the chances of being able to interoperate with services created on different tool stacks/platforms

Answer (score 0):

I Think I finally found the answer to my question
if a standard supports SOAP Envelopes this makes it benefits from all SOAP advantages. like running on different operating systems, with different technologies and programming languages and using the large number of development tools that are available for SOAP